# Javascript, tree structure datamodel

Tags: javascript

I have this to imitate a tree structure:

```
var MODULESYSTEM =
{
    modules:
    {
        a : function() { return 'modules.a'; }
        b : function() { return 'modules.b'; }
        c :
        {
            d : function() { return 'modules.c.d'; }
        }
    }
}
```

so `MODULESYSTEM.modules.a();` is valid, so `MODULESYSTEM.modules.c.d();` too. But what if I want something like `MODULESYSTEM.modules.c();` ? It should return 'modules.c'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to declare that sort of data structure in one line. You will need to build it up procedurally:

```
var MODULESYSTEM = {
    modules: {
        // Other top-level namespace objects
        c: function() {
            return 'modules.c';
        }
    }
};

// Later:
MODULESYSTEM.modules.c.d = function() { return 'modules.c.d'; };
```

There might be a better solution to this problem if you could provide more background about the problem you're looking to solve.

Comment: I wanted to referrer a node as it were a leaf, not an "array"